# How to update parent viewmodel property from usercontrol viewmodel in wpf mvvm pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Im creating a WPF application using MVVM pattern with prism in .net core 6.

In the invoice window, the user can attach support documents and this attaching document interface is created as a user-control.

when user attach a document i need to add that document details to parent window(invoice) viewmodel property.

i have created dependency property in usercontrol like bellow,

```
public partial class DocumentList : UserControl
{
    public DocumentList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

public ObservableCollection<Attachment> Attachments
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Attachment>)GetValue(AttachmentsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AttachmentsProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachmentsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Attachments), typeof(ObservableCollection<Attachment>), typeof(DocumentList), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public bool IsAttachmentDownloadable
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsAttachmentDownloadableProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsAttachmentDownloadableProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsAttachmentDownloadable.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAttachmentDownloadableProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsAttachmentDownloadable", typeof(bool), typeof(DocumentList), new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

}

and my usercontrol viewmodel has property `Attachments`

```
private ObservableCollection<Attachment> _attachments;

public ObservableCollection<Attachment> Attachments
{
    get { return _attachments; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _attachments, value); }
}
```

this attachment collection is bound to grid view

```
 <syncfusion:SfDataGrid 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}"
            x:Name="dataGrid"  
            MaxHeight="100"
                Grid.Row="2"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            SelectionUnit="Row"
            AllowSorting="True"
                ColumnSizer="AutoLastColumnFill"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttachment}">
                <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                    <syncfusion:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Id" MappingName="Id" IsHidden="True"></syncfusion:GridTextColumn>
                    <syncfusion:GridTextColumn HeaderText="File name" MappingName="Name" Width="400"></syncfusion:GridTextColumn>
                    <syncfusion:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Description" MappingName="Description" MinimumWidth="200" Width="438" IsReadOnly="False"></syncfusion:GridTextColumn>
                </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
```

[image]

there is another usercontrol which upload attachments to the server and update this attachment collection, and it works fine , grid is updated as expected.

the issue is i need to bind this usercontrol `Attachments` property to the parent viewmodel property called `Attachments`

my parentviewmodel

```
private ObservableCollection<Attachment> _attachments;

public ObservableCollection<Attachment> Attachments
{
    get { return _attachments; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _attachments, value); }
}
```

and i have bellow binding when calling to user control from parent window

```
 <usrctrl:DocumentList HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                                      IsAttachmentDownloadable="False"
                                      Attachments="{Binding DataContext.Attachments, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Expense_Add}}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

as i said earlier the issue is above binding is not working as expected, can any one help me to sort this out?

Thanks

Comment: I would question why the user control has it's own viewmodel.

Comment: if you preinitialize the observable collection _attachments with dummy values at its definition do these show?
I want to find out if it doesnt bind at all or if it doesnt update

Comment: @DenisSchaf yes if i initialize _attachments collection and add some dummy data , it is showing in the user control

Comment: @Andy i have some logics running inside that usercontroller

Comment: @DenisSchaf As i can see the issue is dependency property is not connected with viewmodel property,

Comment: Why do you believe that all your logic must be implemented in a view model class? There is UI logic and data logic. UI logic belongs to the View alone, usually code-behind or XAML in the form of triggers. If you talk about data related logic than this logic likely belongs to the Model. If the logic is concerned with preparing data for presentation then it belongs to the View Model. That's a rough guide. Each MVVM component has its ow responsibility. You move code to a component based on responsibility and not based on its kind.

Comment: A control must never care about its DataContext. Just develop your control like there is no DataContext property. The DataContext is only relevant for the client of your control. The DataContext is relevant for the "external" data bindings that are set on the control's properties.

Answer (score 1):

The `DocumentList` `UserControl` should not have its own `DataContext`. It should inherit the `DataContext` from its parent element.

You can then bind directly to the `Attachments` property of the parent view model in the window:

```
<usrctrl:DocumentList ... Attachments="{Binding Attachments}"/>
```

In the `UserControl`, you would bind to the local `Attachments` property like this:

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

Comment: can i use this binding with a separate viewmodel for user control?